# Does kaaproject.org has alert engine and timer?

Tags: kaa

I have the following requirement,

- Control heater based on temperature
- If there is motion, send SMS
- Turn garden light on evening
- If water goes low turn on motor

I need alert and timer feature to complete my setup. Is there a way to implement this with `kaaproject.org` ?

Comment: No, I do not try any setup till now. Just collecting required features for my application. I do not see alert/timer feature. Hence I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement this with Kaa. Kaa provides enterprise-grade components for a large majority of established IoT use cases. Look at [IoT Use Cases](http://www.kaaproject.org/iot-use-cases/) section to see what you can do with Kaa.
Read [Key platform features](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/) documentation for the understanding of Kaa platform possibilities.
Also, try [Sandbox](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Getting-started/#sandbox-installation) that illustrate various aspects of the Kaa platform functionality.